# How to pass both model value & text value to controller in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor

I want to pass two values from view to controller . i.e., @Model.idText and value from textbox. here is my code:

```
    @using HTML.BeginForm("SaveData","Profile",FormMethod.Post)
    {
    <a href="someLink">@Model.idText</a>
    <input type="text" name="textValue"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit"/>
    }
```

But problem is if i use "Url.ActionLink() i can get @Model.idText . By post action i can get textbox value using FormCollection . But i need to get both of this value either post or ActionLink

Comment: Your tags are inapropriate : MVC is a design pattern... On what technology stack are you working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using ajax you can achieve this :
don't use form & declare your attributes like this in tags:

```
<a href="someLink">@Model.idText</a>
<input type="text" id="textValue"/>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
```

jquery:

```
    $(function (e) {
        //    Insert
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "some url path",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { textField: $('#textValue').val(), idField: '@Model.idText' },
                success: function (result) {
                    //some code if success
                },
                error: function () {
                    //some code if failed
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
      });
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
@using HTML.BeginForm("SaveData","Profile",FormMethod.Post)
{
   @Html.Hidden("idText", Model.idText)
   @Html.TextBox("textValue")

   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

In your controller

```
public ActionResult SaveData(String idText, String textValue)
{
   return null;
}
```

I'm not sure which part you are struggling with - submitting multiple values to your controller, or getting model binding to work so that values that you have submitted appear as parameters to your action. If you give more details on what you want to achieve I'll amend my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden field in your form - e.g.

```
@Html.Hidden("idText", Model.idText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a rule in global.asax and than compile your your with params using

```
@Html.ActionLink("My text", Action, Controller, new { id = Model.IdText, text =Model.TextValue})
```

Be sure to encode the textvalue, because it may contains invalid chars

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want to engage the ModelBinder to do this for you.  To do that, you need to write your action in your controller with parameters that match the data you want to pass to it.  So, to start with, Iridio's suggestion is correct, although not the full story.  Your view should look like:

```
@using HTML.BeginForm("SaveData","Profile",FormMethod.Post)
{
@Html.ActionLink("My text", MyOtherAction, MaybeMyOtherController, new { id = Model.IdText}) // along the lines of dommer's suggestion...
<input type="text" name="textValue"/>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit"/>
@Html.Hidden("idText", Model.idText)
}
```

Note that I have added the @Html.Hidden helper to add a hidden input field for that value into your field.  That way, the model binder will be able to find this datum.  Note that the Html.Hidden helper is placed WITHIN your form, so that this data will posted to the server when the submit button is clicked.

Also note that I have added dommer's suggestion for the action link and replaced your code.  From your question it is hard to see if this is how you are thinking of passing the data to the controller, or if this is simply another bit of functionality in your code.  You could do this either way:  have a form, or just have the actionlink.  What doesn't make sense is to do it both ways, unless the action link is intended to go somewhere else...??!  Always good to help us help you by being explicit in your question and samples.  Where I think dommer's answer is wrong is that you haven't stated that TextValue is passed to the view as part of the Model.  It would seem that what you want is that TextValue is entered by the user into the view, as opposed to being passed in with the model.  Unlike idText that IS passed in with the Model.

Anyway, now, you need to set up the other end, ie, give your action the necessary

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveData(int idText, string textValue) // assuming idText is an int
{
    // whatever you have to do, whatever you have to return...
}
```

@dommer doesn't seem to have read your code.  However, his suggestion for using the Html.ActionLink helper to create the link in your code is a good one.  You should use that, not the code you have.

### Recapping:

As you are using a form, you are going to use that form to POST the user's input to the server.  To get the idText value that is passed into the View with the Model, you need to use the Html.Hidden htmlhelper.  This must go within the form, so that it is also POSTed to the server.

To wire the form post to your action method, you need to give your action parameters that the ModelBinder can match to the values POSTed by the form.  You do this by using the datatype of each parameter and a matching name.

You could also have a complex type, eg, public class MyTextClass, that has two public properties:

```
public class MyTextClass
{
   public int idText{get;set}
   public string TextValue{get;set;}
}
```

And then in your controller action you could have:

```
public ActionResult SaveData(MyTextClass myText)
{
   // do whatever
}
```

The model binder will now be able to match up the posted values to the public properties of myText and all will be well in Denmark.

HTH.

PS:  You also need to read a decent book on MVC.  It seems you are flying a bit blind.

Another nit pick would be to question the name of your action, SaveData.  That sounds more like a repository method.  When naming your actions, think like a user:  she has simply filled in a form, she has no concept of saving data.  So the action should be Create, or Edit, or InformationRequest, or something more illustrative.  Save Data says NOTHING about what data is being saved.  it could be credit card details, or the users name and telephone...